# Is there any other way you can "wax" as you do when you "wax philosophical"?

Tags: verbs, adjectives, adverbs, copular-verbs, predicative-complements

The *wax* in the phrase "wax philosophical" is a pretty strange bird.  Its *wax* is obviously not the ordinary definition of *wax*, which my dictionary summarizes as an "oily, water-resistant substance", a definition which also serves as a fair summary of other, closely related "waxes", as in earwax or beeswax.

Neither is, I think, the *wax* in "wax philosophical" referring to another sense of *wax*, as in *to grow*, and which I know best in reference to the Moon "waxing and waning"; it means, as best I know, that the Moon is shrinking and growing in size.  So is *waxing philosophical* "growing philosophical"? Sounds pretty strange to me.

The truth is, I only know how to use this set phrase, and can't really break it down into its constituents.  It seems fairly archaic; the *philosophical* isn't even in the standard canonical form of an adverb, with no ending "–ly".  So I was wondering three things:  What is the canonical definition of *wax* as its being used here?  In what other ways can you *wax*? Finally, if *wax* is acting as a verb here, why is it *philosophical*, as an adjective, and not *philosophically* as an adverb?

Comment: Bonus question: Did the noun _wax_ and the putative verb _wax_ originate from the same word?

Comment: I guess you can see by now it's possible to wax many things besides furniture. *Wax lyrical* comes to mind first for me, though I knew there were several alternatives. But it *is* interesting that most logically plausible states *can't* be waxed, or at least don't seem to be. And there does seem to be a certain air of 'set phrase' about the ones we *do* use. Perhaps that's just because the verb *to wax* in this sense is archaic outside the lunar context.

Comment: Wax on. Wax off.

Comment: An old headline in *The Onion:* "Man Waxes Patriotic, Truck"

Comment: I must add that in the Marx Brothers’ movie *Horse Feathers*, college president Groucho, upon being advised, “The Dean is furious! He's waxing wroth!” Replies, “Is Wroth out there too? Tell Wroth to wax the Dean for a while.”

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Merriam-Webster gives [sense 3 for <sup>3</sup>wax:](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/wax%5B3%5D)

> 3: to assume a (specified) characteristic, quality, or state : become <*wax* indignant> <*wax* poetic>”

COCA gives [a nice list](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/?c=coca&q=9855558) of adjectives that are used this way with the verb *wax*:

- WAX ELOQUENT
- WAX ENTHUSIASTIC
- WAX EUPHORIC
- WAX INDIGNANT
- WAX LYRICAL
- WAX NOSTALGIC
- WAX PHILOSOPHIC
- WAX PHILOSOPHICAL
- WAX POETIC
- WAX PROFESSIONAL
- WAX RHAPSODIC
- WAX SENTIMENTAL

When I saw this question, I thought of the phrase “wax poetic” before “wax philosophical”. Indeed, “poetic” occurs 88 times in the corpus with verb *wax* compared to just 30 for “philosophical”.

And of course there is the Sponge [album](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wax_Ecstatic) and [song](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-NVO3cxTbxg) “Wax Ecstatic”.

---

Google N-gram usage data for *wax* + the above adjectives, with credit to hippietrail:

[image: N-gram data for "wax" + adjective]

Comment: Definitely, the most popular ones in my dictionary would be *wax lyrical* and *wax philosophical*.

Comment: I was hoping for "wax stupid".

Comment: The Google Ngram viewer makes a thing of beauty from these phrases and the winners are not the ones I expected. Sometimes it crashes the site though! http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=wax+eloquent%2Cwax+enthusiastic%2Cwax+euphoric%2Cwax+indignant%2Cwax+lyrical%2Cwax+nostalgic%2Cwax+philosophic%2Cwax+philosophical%2Cwax+poetic%2Cwax+professional%2Cwax+rhapsodic%2Cwax+sentimental&year_start=1800&year_end=2011&corpus=0&smoothing=3

Comment: +1 for Sponge reference. And of course the excellent answer.

Answer (score 12):

As I understand it, *to wax* means *to grow*: if you wax philosophical, you **grow philosophical**, which probably means you become philosophically-minded, at least for the moment, and you occupy yourself with philosophical thoughts.

This is the same construction as when you *grow old*: *old* and *philosophical* are best considered subject complements, which is why they are adjectives, not adverbs.

**[Edited:]**
According to [Etymonline.com](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=wax), both come from the Proto-Germanic verb **wakhsan*, "to increase, grow", which in turn comes from Proto-Indo-European **wegs-,* an extended form of the base **aug-*, "to increase". Other dictionaries render this form as **owegs-* or **awegs-*. It is related to *augment*, which has come to us through Latin *augeo*, "to increase", and to Greek *auxô*, also "to increase".

However, a Dutch etymological dictionary, De Vries ([4rd edition, 1997](http://books.google.nl/books?id=9_X44k9-3j8C&q=was#v=onepage&q&f=false), p. 819), is undecided about the etymology of the substance *wax* (Dutch *was*, which is indisputably cognate) and gives Proto-Germanic **wahsa* as a possible origin, related to English *weave*. The Proto-Indo-European root would then be **weg-/*we-*, "weave".

The great *Woordenboek der Nederlandse Taal* ([article *Was (II)* from 1988](http://gtb.inl.nl/iWDB/search?actie=article&wdb=WNT&id=M084017&lemmodern=was)) mentions both origins and says the matter is still undecided. It notes that Latin *cera*, the substance wax, comes from the same root as Latin *cresco*, "to grow", which might support a parallel relation in Proto-Germanic; the substance *wax* would then be "what grows slowly", as the bees add to it incrementally (yes, *increment* comes from Latin *cresco*). Note that the Latin words are no cognates of our word: they come from PIE **ker-*, "knead", the origin of our words *ceramic* (through Greek *kerannumi*, "to knead") and *crescent* (through Latin *cresco*).

However, adds the WNT, modern German has *Wabe*, "honeycomb", which comes from aforementioned PIE **we-*, "weave", and may very well be related to the substance *wax*; in addition, Dutch sometimes had *een(e) was* ("a wax", as opposed to simply "wax") well into the 17th century, which might indicate that the word referred to the piece of wax that constitutes a honeycomb.

A German etymological dictionary, [Köbler (1995)](http://www.koeblergerhard.de/derwbhin.html), is very succinct, but appears to consider the PIE root **we-* cognate to PIE **wegs-*.

Comment: @Cerberus What is the official definition of a subject complement? :)

Comment: @Billare: It is a lexical category unto itself: *I am a man* (a man), *you are foolish* (foolish), *she became fed up* (fed up), *they seemed trustworthy* (trustworthy). It is the complement that is used with copulae (verbs like *to be, become,* etc.) and it qualifies the subject. Cf. the object complement, which only occurs with a kind of verb whose name escapes me, as in *I painted the house black* (black), *she makes me mad, they called her a whore*, etc.

Comment: @Cerberus: You do not mention -- this is perhaps self-evident for you, that the "grow" sense of wax is very much alive in modern German: wachsen - to grow, die Erwachsenen : the adults (= the grown-ups).  Also the imagery for growth is often from plants, so the relation between growing and interweaving (like roots, branches of trees, neighbouring plants of a bush, etc.) is quite natural.

Comment: @ogerard: Hmm the interweaving leaves and roots might be a clue. I am aware of the modern German verb, but I do not know all its connotations. In Dutch, it is pretty much even deader than in English. The verb is archaic, as in the "wassende maan" (waxing moon); we do have neutral "volwassene" (adult, Erwachsene) and old-fashioned/formal "gewas" (domesticated plant). There is also the archaic word "wasdom", maturity. To be honest I do not feel this connotation of weaving at all in Dutch: it is rather like a plain, gradual increase; but, who knows, it might have been there in the beginning.

Comment: @Cerberus: before reading all this interesting material on wax, I interpreted "to wax lyrical" in a mix of "to turn into" and "to quickly apply a polish of", something usually self-deprecatory or unnatural, a kind of temporary madness. The relation with the moon could be : to become philosophical/lyrical/etc. (in a lunatic way) as the moon waxes.

Comment: @ogerard: Haha yeah I often try to hypothesise links between similar words when I'm not sure what they are...

Answer (score 4):

Well, for one thing, it seems archaic because, outside the lunar context, it *is* archaic. Other usages are ironic, poetic, or examples of [Wardour Street English](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/wardour+street): "He waxed wroth, and spake with an angry oath." That sort of thing

Here's the definition from NOAD:

> **wax** 2
>   *verb* [ intrans. ]
>   (of the moon between new and full) have a progressively larger part of its visible surface illuminated, increasing its apparent size.
>   • poetic/literary become larger or stronger : *his anger waxed*.
>   • [with complement ] begin to speak or write about something in the specified manner : *they waxed lyrical about the old days*.

The etymology is OE *weaxen* via Germanic; similar to German *wachsen* (to grow). NOAD gives a slightly different etymology for the noun: OE *wex*, *weax*, Germanic origin, similar to German *Wachs*.

Comment: Is it actually archaic? I've certainly heard and used it in conversation many times in my life, several times a year at least. It's most commonly paired with some form of "poetic" or "philosophic," and less commonly but still regularly with "eloquent" or "nostalgic." How infrequently must a word be used to qualify as archaic?

Comment: @MatthewFrederick: It's almost certainly used ironically in those instances. It's used to cover embarrassment over what many would see as inappropriate use of a philosophical or poetic delivery.

Comment: Hmm. I might be hanging around with weird people, then. More than once someone in my circles have said something like, "Susan waxed philosophically about the role of humans in the environment last night. It was fascinating." Intended as a description of the way she spoke: broadly and perhaps with some amount of musing or tangents. No irony or negative associations.

Comment: @Matthew: But it's almost always said self-consciously, with a wink.

Answer (score 3):

Michael Quinion at [World Wide Words](http://www.worldwidewords.org/qa/qa-wax1.htm) agrees that *wax=to grow* is a difficult idiomatic form to understand in the context of these "*wax*____ " phrases, pointing out that in common use they essentially mean "to communicate in the way described." He continues:

> Sometimes there’s a hint that the person is doing so increasingly — becoming expansive in his language, figuratively increasing or enlarging the specified quality — but that’s present rarely enough that a connection with the “grow” sense of wax can’t be assumed. However, a link exists, since the usage perpetuates one old sense of the verb, “become or turn”, with a nod to another, in which wax before an adjective meant to gradually increase that quality or become it.

In my own brief search of Google books, I found *wax eloquent* the furthest back of the COCA list excerpted here. From *[Bracebridge Hall](http://books.google.com/books?id=NWodAAAAMAAJ&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q=wax&f=false)*, 1822:

[image: http://books.google.com/books?id=NWodAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA29&img=1&zoom=3&hl=en&sig=ACfU3U0Ii-4HTGlJNCHhcdp-34odNSByJA&ci=101%2C1337%2C762%2C155&edge=0]

And found less abstract phrases much further back like *wax bigger* in John Rider's *Bibliotheca Scholastica*, 1589, in a definition of [*pubero*](http://books.google.com/books?ei=dACtTZ2_MsuRgQfrntH2Cw&ct=result&id=luIX3kxlbnkC&dq=inauthor%3a%22John%20Rider%22&q=wax#v=onepage&q=wax%20bigger&f=false).

Comment: *Wax bigger*, in John Rider's Bibliotheca Scholastica, 1589, is probably an early example of tautology - to wax = to increase or grow in size, and the only possible way to grow or increase is "bigger".

Answer (score 1):

I bet someone could wax genial. At least I feel that would be an apt description of (perhaps you know the moment) someone revealing himself to be obviously on my side and supportive of me, for example in a conversation :) Suddenly you feel at home, at ease and you can lose your pretenses.