# What does "waxed rhapsodic" mean?

Tags: idioms, meaning-in-context

See context below:

> Bloomberg is well known for his malapropisms and mispronunciations:
>   he's introduced former Yankee manager Joe Torre as "Joe Torres" [and] waxed
>   rhapsodic about the famous singing duo "Simon and Garfinkle."

Comment: Related: [Is there any other way you can “wax” as you do when you “wax philosophical”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/21673/is-there-any-other-way-you-can-wax-as-you-do-when-you-wax-philosophical)

Comment: "rhapsodic" is the adjective form of "rhapsody" ... meaning "exaggeratedly enthusiastic or ecstatic expression of feeling".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*To wax rhapsodic about something* is a common idiom meaning *to praise something excessively*.

As James indicated, the verb *to wax* is a verb meaning *to grow*, but the verb is very uncommon outside of a few contexts such as this idiom, and when speaking of the phases of the moon.

Comment: Until about a century ago it was almost always ["wax wroth"](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=wax+lyrical%2Cwax+rhapsodic%2Cwax+wroth&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3), but that's hopelessly archaic now. Today it's mainly "wax lyrical", with "rhapsodic" accounting for most of the rest.

Comment: Indeed; "to wax lyrical" is by far the most common variant.

Answer (score 1):

In this context, "to wax" means "to grow." It is also commonly used to describe the moon as it goes from new to full.

Comment: This is incorrect. Bloomberg did not grow rhapsodic about Simon and Garfinkle [sic].

Comment: I grow weary of this pedantry.