# What is the word for thinking philosophically about life?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I want to complete this sentence:

> Here we stand, around ten or fifteen years ago, when I started _____ about life.

The thinking is not necessarily focused on one particular topic. The closet word to *think* I found is ***meditate***, but it too focuses on "religious or spiritual purposes or as a method of relaxation".

Comment: How about "daydreaming"?

Comment: Can you narrow this down a bit for me, please? By *philosophical*, are you referring to *coping with adverse situations*, or are you developing a coherent world view? (Or both, or neither?)

Comment: You may be restricting yourself by assuming the form *[verb] **about** life*, which excludes, for example, *...when I started **reflecting on** life*, or ***...evaluating** life*.

Comment: @HotLicks That's an interesting viewpoint. It could be, but not necessary "during which a person's contact with reality is blurred and partially substituted by a visionary fantasy", as defined in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daydream)

Comment: @Lawrence more on the developing a coherent world view side

Comment: This isn't the part you are asking about, but the first part of the sentence doesn't make sense, from a time perspective: *Here we stand (now?), about ten or fifteen years ago (???)". Not sure what you are trying to say.

Comment: @BradC I imagine that I and the readers rewind the time. Maybe *here we are...*?

Comment: @Ooker Thanks for clarifying. On BradC's comment, the issue is that *now* (via any present tense verb) isn't compatible with *ago*.

Comment: @Ooker Yeah, it would have to either be "there I was, 10 or 15 years ago..." or maybe "It was about 10 or 15 years ago when I..." or something. Unless its a novel where you are doing a deliberate perspective jump, like an older character telling a story from the perspective of their younger selves. But that's a literary device that's hard to do right, not something that should happen in the middle of a sentence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[*Metaphysics*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/metaphysics) is, per Merriam-Webster,

> **a** (1) **:**  a division of philosophy that is concerned with the fundamental nature of reality and being and that includes ontology, cosmology, and often epistemology
>   (2) **:**  ontology 2
>   **b :**  abstract philosophical studies :  a study of what is outside objective experience

which I think may be what you are trying to get at in your description of "thinking philosophically about life". If so, you can use the verb [***metaphysicize***](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/metaphysicize):

> **-ed/-ing/-s
>   :**  to engage in metaphysical speculation

You wouldn't even need to use the last two words of your sentence; you could simply say

> Here we stand, around ten or fifteen years ago, when I started **metaphysicizing/to metaphysicize**.

You don't need to say "about life" since the word on its own includes thinking philosophically about life, the universe, and everything.

On the other hand, if you don't so much mean that you started *thinking deep thoughts* about life but rather that you *became more [philosophical](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/philosophical)* about life, in the sense

> **2 :**  characterized by the attitude of a philosopher; specifically :  calm or unflinching in the face of trouble, defeat, or loss

then you may want to use a longer phrase like "to become more philosophical" or "to be more contemplative" or "to attain serenity".

Comment: Getting serious.....?

Comment: @Xanne Not sure what you mean?

Comment: @0xFEE1DEAD Couldn't tell you. There were at least half a dozen upvoted (by me) answers when I posted, so I wasn't expecting it. But it must capture what the OP was looking for.

Answer (score 16):

One choice would be **ruminating**. See **ruminate** defined by [Oxford dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/ruminate) as

> Think deeply about something.

Comment: I prefer "chewing your cud".

Answer (score 10):

To [***ponder***](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ponder)

> to think or consider especially quietly, soberly, and deeply

Used in your sentence, it would probably work best as "pondering life," rather than "pondering *about* life."

Answer (score 9):

I would use *[contemplate](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/contemplate)*, and simply drop the word "about":

> Here we stand, around ten or fifteen years ago, when I started contemplating life.

Comment: Snap! (An hour later ...)

Answer (score 7):

To ***[philosophise](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/philosophize):***
​

> to talk for a long time about subjects such as the meaning of life:
>
> - Students, she complained, had nothing better to do than spend whole days philosophizing about the nature of truth.

(Cambridge Dictionary)

Also
***[speculate](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/speculate)*** conveys a more general and wider sense of thinking about something:

> - to meditate on or ponder a subject :  *reflect*

(M-W)

Comment: can *philosophise* works on thinking alone? No, I suppose?

Comment: @Ooker - yes, it may refer to thinking.

Answer (score 7):

muse ([MWD](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/muse))

> to become absorbed in thought; especially :  to think about something carefully and thoroughly musing about what might have been

Answer (score 3):

> Here we stand, around ten or fifteen years ago, when I started thinking
>    **existentially** about life.

If something is existential, it has to do with human existence. If you wrestle with big questions involving the meaning of life, you may be having an existential crisis. ([vocabulary.com](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/existential))

Answer (score 2):

Philosophize, or philosophise, is probably the most suited to this task especially since it consists of the word and a suffix

http://www.thefreedictionary.com/philosophize

> Here we stand, around ten or fifteen years ago, when I started *philosophising* about life.

Answer (score 2):

***contemplation:***
​

> deep reflective thought:
>
> - he would retire to his room for study or contemplation.

([Mac OS Dictionary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dictionary_(software)))

Answer (score 2):

There are still many options :

> [Cogitate](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cogitate) -  to think over.
>
> [Perpend](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/perpend) - to reflect on carefully.

Comment: it's worth noting that most people probably wouldn't understand these words. i don't think they're good choices for most audiences for that reason.

Comment: I like cogitate. Anybody familiar with Descarte's _"cogito ergo sum"_ should be able to understand.

Answer (score 1):

I would consider saying you began to "wax philosophical."

> Wax philosophical - To take on a quality or state of thinking or talking of deep subjects such as the meaning of life.

[Is there any other way you can "wax" as you do when you "wax philosophical"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/21673/is-there-any-other-way-you-can-wax-as-you-do-when-you-wax-philosophical)

Answer (score 1):

Apart from ponder and contemplate, I would say you could use [**mull**](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/mulling) -

> **Think about (something) deeply and at length.**
>
> "She began to *mull* over the various notions to life"

It gives a feeling of serious contemplation which could be expected when one is thinking about topics like the one you have described.